# Expression engine Forms module include html section

Tags: devdemon-forms

I run expression engine **v2.10.1** with **exp:resso store 2.5.1** and have installed **Forms module 3.5.3.**

I created a test form and included it [here](http://www.growingpaper.nl/offerte/test)

I have included a HTML section in the form where i load the current Cart contents.

**My Question:** Is it possible to include the shown html section in the form submission?

If not, is there another way to include current cart into a Form entry?

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is it possible to include the shown html section in the form submission?
Answer: technically NO!.

But you can create a hidden field or hidden textarea and save the html into that field via JQuery.

Comment: ok, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I found this thread, but in EE Forms i cannot change the ID for the hidden field and neither can i edit the button to include onclick="submitMyForm()":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103524/populate-hidden-form-element-value-with-the-value-of-a-text-field-on-form-submit

Comment: Main issue here is that the hidden field has no ID

Comment: Solution is:
Create an extra TextArea field from forms module. you will get the default ID for this field. Use CSS and hide TextArea field with "display: none;". Use JQuery to copy the HTML into TextArea field. and its done !!

Comment: Much appreciated! Too bad cant get it working yet: this is the script: <script type="text/javascript">                
                    $('#new_submission').submit(function() {
                        $('#forms_field_50').val($('#forms_field_44').val());
                    }
    </script>

Comment: Try this: $('#ddform_50').val($('#forms_field_44').html())

Comment: Also I suggest you to use this code:

 `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('submit', 'form#new_submission', function(event) {
    $('#ddform_50').val($('#forms_field_44').html())
   });
  });
 </script>`

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!!!

Comment: Thanks :)  Can you please upvote the answer if it works fine for you.

Comment: i did but my points are low still..Anyway i can help you with exposure elseway pls let me know!

Comment: he he. Its ok brother.